# Cocoapods with use_frameworks!: Xcode complains file not found on import but can Opt-Click it still

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, realm, ios-frameworks

Some pods I use require me to `use_frameworks!` but for some reason I'm getting compile time errors on my import statements.

I'm on Cocoapods 1.0.0 and Xcode 7.3

For example

`#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>`
error: 'Bolts/Bolts.h' file not found

but the annoying part is option clicking it takes me to the source file for Bolts.h so it's clearly linked on some level, why doesn't the compiler make the connection?

This is happening on a few different, but not all, of my pods. Interestingly, though, this error seems to be absent on different files even on the same exact Pod (so essentially, I won't get the Bolts.h file not found warning on every file I try to import it in - and I have the continue building after errors option enabled on my Xcode so I don't think it's because some sort of process cut the compilation analyses short.

Note: there is actually one Pod, Realm, that I get a compile warning on, and that opt-clicking gives me a ? so not sure if something special is going on there.

Comment: Did you solve this yet?

Comment: Indirectly, i had two pods that both required frameworks and for some reason they didn't play well together (no errors when I included them individually but when they both were in I would get this behavior). I just ended up integrating them both manually and removing the use_frameworks and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem.  I deleted out the contents of the DerivedData folder, restarted Xcode, cleaned the project, and built it to fix.

Comment: This should be a comment